# Webpack proxy, how to redirect when url end with specific path?

Tags: javascript, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I'd like that when i try to access this URL :

http://localhost:8080/123456/activites-digitales

Proxy redirect request to this address :

http://localhost:8082/activites-digitales

I have an api on port 8082 which return JSON.

With my current config file it work for :

http://localhost:8080/activites-digitales

But not :

http://localhost:8080/123456/activites-digitales

123456 could be any number, it's a route parameter, what should i change in my configuration ?

I've got the following devServer conf :

```
devServer: {
    hotOnly: true,
    index: 'index.html',
    port: 8080,
    proxy: {
      '/activites-digitales': 'http://localhost:8082/'
    }
}
```

I ever tried '*/activites-digitales', '/**/activites-digitales'

webpack and webpack-dev-server 2.3

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pathRewrite config like the below:

```
proxy: {
            "/123456/activites-digitales": {
                target: "http://localhost:8082/",
                pathRewrite: {"^/123456": ""}
            }
        }
```

More info [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy)

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting your host port 8080 to port 8082 in your code.

```
http://localhost:8082/
```

Comment: I know, it's desired, i have a little app on port 8082 which return JSON, i'll add the precision, thanks to help me improve my post.