# Webpack - Redirecting multiple pages

Tags: pdf, url, webpack, redirect

I have some pdf files on my website, lets call them `a,b,c,d` (all ending with `.pdf`).
These files don't sit all under the same path (there is a total of 3 different directories), for example we have

```
https://example.com/first_dir/a.pdf
https://example.com/first_dir/b.pdf
https://example.com/second_dir/c.pdf
https://example.com/third_dir/d.pdf
```

I have the following alias dictionary:

```js
name_conversions = {
    'first_name'       : 'first_dir/a.pdf'
    'other_name'       : 'first_dir/b.pdf' 
    'another_name'     : 'second_dir/c.pdf'
    'yet_another_name' : 'third_dir/d.pdf' 
}
```

and I want to create redirections according to this dictionary, so that when we access `https://example.com/first_name` we get redirected to `https://example.com/first_dir/a.pdf`, and same goes for the other entries.

---

How can this be done in webpack? If this can't be done in webpack what are the alternatives, that hopefully don't require me making a lot of new files, one per pdf, and don't require creating copies of these pdfs.

I've [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535211/webpack-proxy-how-to-redirect-when-url-end-with-specific-path) people use `webpack proxy` for this, but this is not for production from what I understood, and only for development.

**Update**: I found a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redirect-webpack-plugin) for doing redirects, but I can seem to find how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I can use the package `redirect-webpack-plugin`.

All I need to do is the following:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new RedirectWebpackPlugin({
            redirects: name_conversions
        })
        ...
    ]
    ...
}
```